# Jenkins: Automate CI Docker instance

Tags: docker, jenkins, automation

I'm trying to setup Jenkins to be fully automated once I launch it from a docker container.

My question is how do I automate the configuration of the global Jenkins settings.  For example the items in manage jenkins and credentials?

I'm using this a reference:

```
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/remote+access+api
```

Currently, I have the set these items up manually. I would like to fully automate the CI server creation.  Is this possible with Jenkins or is there some human intervention that is required?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we used chef to setup the master , and it run some groovy scripts to install all the plugin and configuration. it almost done fully automatically , beside 1 or 2 plugins that I didn't find the syntax to configure all others works fine.

I installed all the plugins using Jenkins CLI , check yourJenkins/cli/ for reference.

for the general configuration you can install all the tools

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

def inst1 = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc1 = inst1.getDescriptor("hudson.tools.JDKInstaller")
println desc1.doPostCredential('buildJenkins@gmail.com','JenkinsOracleXXXXX')

import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.tools.*

// JDK installation
def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc = inst.getDescriptor("hudson.model.JDK")

def versions = [
    "jdk-1.8.101": "jdk-8u101-oth-JPR",
//    "jdk-1.8.102": "jdk-8u102-oth-JPR"
]
```

general variables

```
// general properties
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

newEnvVarsNodeProperty = null
envVars = null

if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
  globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
  envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
} else {
  envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()

}
envVars.put("ARTIFACTORY_URL", "artifactory-url")
envVars.put("ARTIFACTORY_USER", "jenkins")
envVars.put("DOCKER_USER", "docker-push")


instance.save()
```

email address

```
// admin Email
def jenkinsLocationConfiguration = JenkinsLocationConfiguration.get()
jenkinsLocationConfiguration.setAdminAddress('admin@yours.com')
jenkinsLocationConfiguration.save()
```

there a lot of examples , just look for groovy Jenkins configuration ..
if you have any specific question let me know.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.